# All possible variants of representation natural number N as product of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Task : describe a predicate (on Prolog) that count all possible variants of representation of natural number N as product of natural numbers. For example, 6 = 6*1 = 2*3, so answer is 2. The program itself isn't a problem, but main algorithm is hard for me. I get stuck

Comment: From your example you seem to only count products of two numbers, and the order of the factors is unimportant.  Is that correct?

Comment: @paw88789 yes, but 6*1 and 1*6 the same. For my example, answer is 2, not 4.Order of the factors is unimportant.

Comment: Does $24=2*3*4$ count, or only products of two factors?

Comment: oh, sorry, my mistake. @RossMillikan you right.

Comment: There is this [MSE link for repeated factors admitted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629406/) and this [MSE link for repeated factors not admitted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250364/).

Comment: the solution isn't so simple as i expected. Thank for link, @MarkoRiedel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given number $N$ with prime factorization $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, the total number of positive integer factors is given by the well-known formula, $d(N)=(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$.

The factors generally pair up to give $N$ as a product of two factors.  For instance, $24=2^3\cdot 3$ has $(3+1)(1+1)=8$ factors, which pair up to give $24=1\cdot 24=2\cdot 12=3\cdot8=4\cdot 6$

However in the case that $N$ is a perfect square, there is one factor (namely $\sqrt{N}$ that pairs with itself.

Thus the number of ways of writing $N$ as a product of two factors is $\left\lceil\frac{d(N)}{2}\right\rceil$, where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function of $x$.

Comment: thank you! No doubt, brilliant answer. Unfortunately i mistaken in explanation, so variants like 24 = 4*3*2 is possible. Can i use first formula from you answer?